# Как изменить свойство HorizontalAlighment через код?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]У меня есть `TextBlock` с именем textBlockMsg.
Как мне получить к нему доступ в коде, в public function

xaml код:

```
<ListBox x:Name="listBoxMessages" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Width="342">

                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        </Grid>

                        <StackPanel Grid.Column="0">
                            <TextBlock x:Name="textBlockMsg" FontSize="12" Text="{Binding Path=Msg}" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                        </StackPanel>

                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

если переменная i = 0, у TextBlock'a HorizontalAlighment должно принять значение Left.
если переменная i = 1, у TextBlock'a HorizontalAlighment должно принять значение Right.

Comment: Подробнее опишите что вы хотите изменить и разметку покажите. В каком контейнере этот ваш TextBlock лежит? Из разметки работает?

Comment: из разметки работает

Comment: Покажите как выглядит в разметке то, что вы хотите сделать из кода

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Смотрите, вы должны действовать через привязку.

Предположим, у нас имеется такой класс, представляющий собой одно сообщение:

```
class Message
{
    public Direction Direction { get; }
    public string Text { get; }
    public Message(string text, Direction direction)
    {
        Direction = direction;
        Text = text;
    }
}
```

где `Direction`:

```
enum Direction
{
    Incoming, Outgoing
}
```

В разметке вы должны привязать свойство `HorizontalAlignment` к `Direction` сообщения, но так как типы отличаются - напишем такой простой конвертер:

```
class DirectionToAlignmentConverter : MarkupExtension, IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var dir = (Direction)value;
        if (dir == Direction.Incoming) return HorizontalAlignment.Left;
        if (dir == Direction.Outgoing) return HorizontalAlignment.Right;
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider) => this;
}
```

Он получает значение типа `Direction` и если оно равно `Incoming` - возвращает `HorizontalAlignment.Left`, а если оно равно `Outgoing` - `HorizontalAlignment.Right`

Теперь разметка:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Messages}">
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}"
                       HorizontalAlignment="{Binding Direction,
                           Converter={local:DirectionToAlignmentConverter}}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Ну и я создал коллекцию с примером данных:

```
public List<Message> Messages { get; } = new List<Message>
{
    new Message("Hello, Sasha!", Direction.Incoming),
    new Message("Hello, Klim!", Direction.Outgoing),
    new Message("How are you, Sasha?", Direction.Incoming),
    new Message("Bla-bla-bla", Direction.Outgoing)
};
```

Получилось вот что:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Я не могу обратиться к textBlockMsg, так как не удалось найти тип или имя пространства имён

Comment: @Klimbo, ах, я понял, у вас же там `DataTemplate`, сейчас дополню ответ

Comment: Буду с нетерпением ждать, заранее спасибо

Comment: Обновил ответ, @Klimbo

Comment: Огромное спасибо!

Comment: Пожалуйста! Если что непонятно по примеру - спрашивайте

Comment: Андрей, я сильно извиняюсь, у меня почему-то не выводятся сообщения. Не могли ли бы вы скинуть программу архивом, чтобы я посмотрел, что у меня не так сделано.

Comment: @Klimbo: http://rgho.st/7ChlQNDHC

Comment: Не написал DataContext = this; ,спасибо за помощь)

Comment: Как чуть освоитесь в WPF обязательно ознакомьтесь с паттерном MVVM